# Adding hours (00 to 23) to date column

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I worked on a data set and was able to rearrange it this way ([pastebin](https://pastebin.com/raw/L6zQvmuU)).

```
         date type  value location
0  2017-10-03    D   3035    INDIA
0  2017-10-03    D   3035    INDIA
0  2017-10-03    D   3035    INDIA
0  2017-10-03    D   3035    INDIA
0  2017-10-03    D   3035    INDIA
   ................................
   total 24 rows for D type and India
   ................................
1  2017-10-03    F   3035    INDIA
1  2017-10-03    F   3035    INDIA
1  2017-10-03    F   3035    INDIA
1  2017-10-03    F   3035    INDIA
1  2017-10-03    F   3035    INDIA
   ................................
   total 24 rows for F type and India
   ................................
2  2017-10-03    D   3035    CHINA
2  2017-10-03    D   3035    CHINA
2  2017-10-03    D   3035    CHINA
2  2017-10-03    D   3035    CHINA
2  2017-10-03    D   3035    CHINA
   ................................
   total 24 rows for D type and China
   ................................
```

Expected output: I want to add hours (from 00:00 to 23:00) to the date column. There are exactly 24 rows for a `date, type, location`. So I just have to loop through date column, take first 24 rows, append time (00:00 to 23:00), then do the same for next 24 rows and so on...

```
0  2017-10-03 00:00   D   3035    INDIA
0  2017-10-03 01:00   D   3035    INDIA
0  2017-10-03 02:00   D   3035    INDIA
0  2017-10-03 03:00   D   3035    INDIA
0  2017-10-03 04:00   D   3035    INDIA
   ................................
   total 24 rows for D type and India
   ................................
1  2017-10-03 01:00    F   3035    INDIA
1  2017-10-03 02:00    F   3035    INDIA
1  2017-10-03 03:00    F   3035    INDIA
1  2017-10-03 03:00    F   3035    INDIA
1  2017-10-03 04:00    F   3035    INDIA
```

Comment: Do yourself a favor: put timezones on them while you're at it. I promise some poor sap down the line (maybe even yourself!) will be glad you did.

Comment: @jpmc26: Good advice! Added it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by index with [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for count and then convert it to `hour` [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html) which is added to `date`s:

```
#convert to datetime if necessary
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df['date'] += pd.to_timedelta(df.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), unit='H')
```

---

```
print (df.head(30))

                 date type  value location
0 2017-10-03 00:00:00    D   3035    INDIA
0 2017-10-03 01:00:00    D   3035    INDIA
0 2017-10-03 02:00:00    D   3035    INDIA
0 2017-10-03 03:00:00    D   3035    INDIA
0 2017-10-03 04:00:00    D   3035    INDIA
0 2017-10-03 05:00:00    D   3035    INDIA
0 2017-10-03 06:00:00    D   3035    INDIA
0 2017-10-03 07:00:00    D   3035    INDIA
0 2017-10-03 08:00:00    D   3035    INDIA
0 2017-10-03 09:00:00    D   3035    INDIA
0 2017-10-03 10:00:00    D   3035    INDIA
0 2017-10-03 11:00:00    D   3035    INDIA
0 2017-10-03 12:00:00    D   3035    INDIA
0 2017-10-03 13:00:00    D   3035    INDIA
0 2017-10-03 14:00:00    D   3035    INDIA
0 2017-10-03 15:00:00    D   3035    INDIA
0 2017-10-03 16:00:00    D   3035    INDIA
0 2017-10-03 17:00:00    D   3035    INDIA
0 2017-10-03 18:00:00    D   3035    INDIA
0 2017-10-03 19:00:00    D   3035    INDIA
0 2017-10-03 20:00:00    D   3035    INDIA
0 2017-10-03 21:00:00    D   3035    INDIA
0 2017-10-03 22:00:00    D   3035    INDIA
0 2017-10-03 23:00:00    D   3035    INDIA
1 2017-10-03 00:00:00    F   3035    INDIA
1 2017-10-03 01:00:00    F   3035    INDIA
1 2017-10-03 02:00:00    F   3035    INDIA
1 2017-10-03 03:00:00    F   3035    INDIA
1 2017-10-03 04:00:00    F   3035    INDIA
1 2017-10-03 05:00:00    F   3035    INDIA
```